# Why is null being assigned to this variable?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

So I've just discovered the null coalescing ternary operator but I can't seem to figure out why my variable is still being set to null in the line of code below.

```
MenuItem parent = (treeView.SelectedItem ?? treeView.Items[0]) as MenuItem;
```

The object `treeView` does have multiple items.

No matter if the `treeView` has a selected item or not the variable is always null.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps its not a `MenuItem`? `as T` will return `null` if it doesn't cast.

Comment: The null coalescing operator is a binary operator, not a ternary operator.

Comment: It's ternary according to DotNetPerls, @Servy

Comment: @TobySmith Then it's wrong there too.  Notice how there's two operands, not three.

Comment: @TobySmith `??` has two operands. DotNetPerls ins't an argument-terminating authority; MSDN is. And you'll find that MSDN agrees with Servy.

Comment: it doesn't even call it that: https://www.dotnetperls.com/null-coalescing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`treeView.SelectedItem` may or may not be null, but it's never a `MenuItem`.

`treeView.Items[0]` may or may not be null, but it's never a `MenuItem`.

This expression...

```
(treeView.SelectedItem ?? treeView.Items[0])
```

...returns the value of `treeView.SelectedItem` if that value isn't null. If that value is null, the expression returns `treeView.Items[0]`. Probably better to say "it returns the first non-null operand".

Whichever of those you get, you then use `as` to try to cast it to a `MenuItem`. The cast never succeeds, because the actual object you're casting can never be cast to `Menuitem`.

`as` returns `null` when the cast is not possible.

So you always get `null`.

When you get a situation like this, put in a breakpoint and hover the mouse over all the operands for the expression. Once you know what the operands *really are*, you can select subexpressions like `(treeView.SelectedItem ?? treeView.Items[0])` and hover over those. If you have any questions, don't just try to stare down the code and sweat it out from first principles like Bertrand Russell. Looking at the values in the debugger will provide critical information you'd never think of.

### Update

But your real problem is that you have, in some way I haven't identified, populated a WPF TreeView with MenuItems, and you want to get the selected menu item back out. I've tried to reproduce what you did, and the Items collection on my treeview is full of MenuItems, but you say you're seeing TreeViewItems. So I'm not sure what's going on.

This strikes me as a bad way to populate a TreeView in any case. I'd suggest a collection of a mini-viewmodel class, bound to the TreeView's ItemsSource property. There are plenty of examples of this on Stack Overflow. That's the way WPF wants you to do it, and I've found that WPF is extremely unfriendly if you don't do things the way it wants you to.

Comment: Ah OK - so how do I then cast the result to a `MenuItem`?

Comment: @TobySmith The result is not a `MenuItem` and so can't be cast to one. I think that the result might be a `TreeViewItem`, but you can easily check that guess by putting in a breakpoint and using the watch window. Can you go into more detail about what you wanted this code to accomplish?

Comment: @TobySmith This is WPF, is it? Or some flavor of XAML? How are you populating your TreeView?

Comment: It is WPF, I populate `treeView` with `MenuItems` to represent directories and files within a location. Yeah the result is showing as a `TreeViewItem`.

Comment: @TobySmith Aha! Try expanding its properties in the watch window -- see if its DataContext is a MenuItem

Comment: I just wanted the variable to have the selected item if one else the topmost item which I assumed is always index 0?

Comment: I think you may be right about that but you can figure that out once you've got the MenuItem you want. Try looking at the tv item's DataContext, I think you may find your MenuItem there.

Comment: I'd strongly advise writing some kind of mini-viewmodel class for the treeview item objects rather than using MenuItem -- give it a string DisplayName property, a collection of Children, etc. I mean, you can get it working with what you've got, but you'll have nicer and more easily maintained code if you write a special class for the purpose.

Comment: Really sorry! I unexpectedly had to step away for a bit. Thank you for the update and advice though :)

I'm looking into changing my work to use TreeViewItems